# How to align category labels in kendo ui line chart?

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui

I have a kendo ui line chart setup with about 80 data points. These data points span over 5 categories.

The category labels all bunch to the left side of the chart and I'm not sure how to get them spread across the width of the chart area.

Here is the jsfiddle with demo data:

http://jsfiddle.net/robotsushi/kETTu/5/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future reference the scenario described above is not possible. 
It needs to be done with a scatter line chart.